# Generating similar estimates of interactions in afex, lsmeans, and lme4 packages

Tags: r, lme4, lsmeans

I would like to know if there is a way get the same estimates of an interaction effect in afex & lsmeans packages as in lmer. The toy data below is for two groups with different intercepts and slopes.

```
set.seed(1234)
A0 <- rnorm(4,2,1)
B0 <- rnorm(4,2+3,1)
A1 <- rnorm(4,6,1)
B1 <- rnorm(4,6+2,1)
A2 <- rnorm(4,10,1)
B2 <- rnorm(4,10+1,1)
A3 <- rnorm(4,14,1)
B3 <- rnorm(4,14+0,1)
score <- c(A0,B0,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3)
id <- factor(rep(1:8,times = 4, length = 32))
time <- factor(rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32))
timeNum <- as.numeric(rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32))
group <- factor(rep(c("A","B"), times =2, each = 4, length = 32))
df <- data.frame(id, group, time, timeNum, score)
df
```

And here is the plot

```
(ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = score, group = group)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", aes(linetype = group)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", aes(shape = group), size = 3) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,18)))
```

When I run a standard `lmer` on the data looking for an estimate of the difference in change in `score` over `time` between `group`s.

```
summary(modelLMER <- lmer(score ~ group * timeNum + (timeNum|id), df))
```

I get an estimate for the `group*time` interaction of `-1.07`, which means that the increase in score for a one-unit increase in time is ~1 point less in `group B` than `group A`. This estimate matches the preset differences I built into the dataset.

What I would like to know is how to do a similar thing in the `afex` and `lsmeans` packages.

```
library(afex)
library(lsmeans)
```

First I generated the `afex` model object

```
modelLM <- aov_ez(id="id", dv="score", data=df, between="group", within="time", 
                 type=3, return="lm")
```

Then passed that into the `lsmeans` function

```
lsMeansLM <- lsmeans(modelLM, ~rep.meas:group)
```

My goal is to generate an *accurate* estimate of the `group*time` interaction in afex and lsmeans. To do so requires specifying custom contrast matrices based on the split specified in the `lsmeans` function above.

```
groupMain = list(c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1)) # group main effect
linTrend = list(c(-3,-1,1,3,-3,-1,1,3)) # linear trend
linXGroup = mapply("*", groupMain, linTrend) # group x linear trend interaction
```

Then I made a master list

```
contrasts <- list(groupMain=groupMain, linTrend=linTrend, linXGroup=linXGroup)
```

Which I passed into the `contrast` function in `lsmeans`.

```
contrast(lsMeansLM, contrasts)
```

The *F* and *p* values in the output match those for the automatic tests for linear trend and for the group difference in linear trend generated from a mixed ANCOVA in SPSS. However the mixed ANCOVA does not generate an estimate.

The estimate of the effect using the procedure above, instead of being approx. -1, like in the `lmer` (and matching the difference I built into the data) is approx. -10, which is wildly inaccurate.

I assume it has something to do with how I am coding the contrast coefficients. I know if I normalise the coefficients of the `groupMain` matrix by dividing all coefficients by four that yields an accurate estimate of the main effect of group averaged across all timepoints. But I have no idea how to get an accurate estimate either of linear trend averaged across groups (`linTrend`), *or* an accurate estimate of the difference in linear trend across groups (`linXGroup`).

I am not sure if this question is more suitable for here or Cross Validated. I figured here first because it seems to be software related, but I know there are probably deeper issues involved. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `timeNum` is a numeric predictor. Therefore, the interaction is a comparison of *slopes*. Note this:

```
> lstrends(modelLMER, ~group, var = "timeNum")
 group timeNum.trend       SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 A          4.047168 0.229166 6.2 3.490738 4.603598
 B          2.977761 0.229166 6.2 2.421331 3.534191

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
> pairs(.Last.value)
 contrast estimate        SE  df t.ratio p.value
 A - B    1.069407 0.3240897 6.2     3.3  0.0157
```

There's your 1.07 - the opposite sign because the comparison is in the other direction.

I will further explain that the `lsmeans` result you describe in the question is a comparison of the two group *means*, not an interaction contrast. `lsmeans` uses a reference grid:

```
> ref.grid(modelLMER)
'ref.grid' object with variables:
    group = A, B
    timeNum = 1.5
```

and as you can see, `timeNum` is being held fixed at its mean of 1.5. The LS means are predictions for each group at `timeNum` = 1.5 -- often called the adjusted means; and the difference is thus the difference between those two adjusted means.

Regarding the discrepancy claimed in obtaining your linear contrast of about 10.7: The linear contrast coefficients `c(-3,-1,1,3)` give you a *multiple* of the slope of the line. To get the slope, you need to divide by `sum(c(-3,-1,1,3)^2)` -- and also multiply by 2, because the contrast coefficients increment by 2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @rvl. Was very pleased to learn two new functions, `lstrends()` and `.Last.value`, that I wasn't aware of before. In the `modelLM` object I used the `time` variable, which is a factor, not the `timeNum` variable. I was wondering if there was any way to generate an accurate estimate of the differences between linear trend using the `modelLM` object and the contrast matrices I specified in `lsmeans` (i.e. rather than using the `modelLMER` object)?

Comment: What about `lsmeans(lsmeansLM, interaction = c("poly","pairwise")`?

Comment: @llewmills Note I added a discussion of the linear contrast to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @rvl. Though I got an error when I ran the function in your comment, your edits to your original answer allowed me to work up normalised matrices that obtained me accurate estimates of differences in slope and main effect. I wish I could accept your answer more than once!

Comment: I guess there is a missing closing parenthesis. Otherwise it will work.

Comment: No the error is `Error in lsmeans(modelLM, interaction = c("poly", "pairwise")) : argument "specs" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Oops should have.been `contrast()` not `lsmeans()`

Comment: Ah yes that worked. But the estimate of linear trend is out by that same margin of ten. Where did you learn how to normalise the linear trend coefficients like that @rvl? Also how would you transform quadratic and cubic trend coefficients, given that the incremental change across those is not consistent?

Comment: Lots of standard design textbooks have a section on orthogonal polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the invaluable help of @rvl I was able to solve this. Here is the code.

In order to generate the correct contrast matrices we first need to normalise them

```
(mainMat <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1)) # main effects matrix
(trendMat <- c(-3,-1,1,3,-3,-1,1,3) # linear trend contrast coefficients 
(nTimePoints <- 4) # number of timePoints
(mainNorm <- 1/nTimePoints)
(nGroups <- 2) # number of between-Ss groups
(trendIncrem <- 2) # the incremental increase of each new trend contrast coefficient    
(trendNorm <- trendIncrem/(sum(trendMat^2))) # normalising the trend coefficients
```

Now we create several contrast matrices in the form of lists. These are normalised using the objects we created above

```
(groupMain = list(mainMat*mainNorm)) # normalised group main effect
(linTrend = list(trendMat*trendNorm)) # normalised linear trend
(linXGroup = list((mainMat*trendMat)*(nGroups*trendNorm))) # group x linear trend interaction
```

Now pass those lists of matrices into a master list

```
contrasts <- list(groupMain=groupMain, linTrend=linTrend, linXGroup=linXGroup)
```

And pass that master list into the `contrasts` function in lsmeans

```
contrast(lsMeansLM, contrasts)
```

This is the output

```
 contrast                                               estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 c(-0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)  1.927788 0.2230903  6   8.641  0.0001
 c(-0.15, -0.05, 0.05, 0.15, -0.15, -0.05, 0.05, 0.15)  3.512465 0.1609290  6  21.826  <.0001
 c(0.3, 0.1, -0.1, -0.3, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3)         -1.069407 0.3218581  6  -3.323  0.0160
```

How do we check if these are accurate estimates?

Note first that the estimate of the `group*time` interaction is now approximately the same value as is returned by

```
summary(modelLMER)
```

The 'main effect' trend (for want of a better descriptor), which is the rate of change in score across the four time points *averaged across both levels of group*, is 3.51. If we change the coding of the `group` factor to simple coding via

```
contrasts(df$group) <- c(-.5,.5)
```

and run `summary(modelLMER)` again, the `time` estimate will now be 3.51.

Finally for the main effect of group, that is, the difference in score between groups averaged across all time points. We can run

```
pairs(lsmeans(modelLM,"group"))
```

And this will be -1.92. Thank you @rvl. A great answer. Using `afex` and `lsmeans` we have now forced a mixed ANCOVA that treats the repeated measures variable as categorical to give us estimates of group differences in trend and main effects that match those returned by a mixed-effects model where the repeated measures variable is continuous, *and* with *p*- and *F*-values that match those of SPSS.